# WebBrowser - How to click that button

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to click on a button with the following HTML code :

```
<button type="submit">Go</button>
```

I tried to use the following code :

```
        For Each myHtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.All
            If myHtmlElement.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
                myHtmlElement.InvokeMember("Click")
            End If
        Next
```

I got no results, so I catched the following error :

> reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Where are you using this code? Are you sure the Document is already loaded? You should subscribe to the `DocumentCompleted` event, where you also check whether `WebBrowser2.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete`. You should also count the number of Frames and filter the `Document.Body` collection to only return `Button` elements.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the form is loaded the WebBrowser navigates to a page:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser2.Navigate("<URL>")
End Sub
```

Then when the page has finished loading, the `GetElementsByTagName` function can be used to retrieve the `<input>` HtmlElements.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser2.DocumentCompleted
    For Each myHtmlElement In WebBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If myHtmlElement.GetAttribute("type") = "submit" Then
            myHtmlElement.InvokeMember("Click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Waiting for the page to load (using the `DocumentCompleted` event) is important; if I execute the 'click'-code without waiting then in my case nothing happens after the page is shown, or in you case it may throw the error.